# ipconfig shows IAID, DUID for IPv6 config; where can I get these in native PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ipv6, dhcp

I'm either missing something incredibly obvious or ... I don't know what.  I've scoured support sites for this information, but I keep finding either server-side information or IPv4-era documentation for finding configuration details.

In order to manage IPv6 on my network more coherently, I want to be able to programmatically find the DUID + IAID pair for any DHCPv6-enabled NIC on a workstation.  The information appears plainly when one runs `ipconfig /all`,

```
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : nnnnnnnnn
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : nn-nn-nn-[etc.]
```

What is the PowerShell-native way to find these?

Answer (score 0):

All right, well, I continue to be stumped that there's no more straightforward and plainly documented way to do this, but at least this *works* as far as I can see.  Anyone have a *better* approach?

```
$nicguid = (get-netadapter *IFALIAS HERE*).deviceid
$niciaid = get-itempropertyvalue "HKLM:System\CurrentControlSet\services\TCPIP6\Parameters\interfaces\$nicguid" -name "dhcpv6iaid"
$nicduid = (get-itempropertyvalue "HKLM:System\CurrentControlSet\services\TCPIP6\Parameters" -name "dhcpv6duid") -join ''
```

Comment: The value stored for the DUID is hex, so it should be: `((Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters).Dhcpv6DUID | % {'{0:x2}' -f $_ }) -join "-"`. Personally, I don't know of any way to get that info either without doing much longer code than a query to the registry. Here's a good understanding on a DUID is, and how it's formed: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3315#section-9/

Comment: Same for the comment [here](https://www.briefmenow.org/microsoft/which-two-values-should-you-obtain-from-server2/).

Comment: Thanks!  I had weird experiences with what format the GUI editor for DHCP (on Windows Server 2016) will and won't accept, so I definitely hadn't given any thought yet to proper range-checking or separators.  I appreciate the clarification.